# I want to write a flutter video plug-in on Android. I want to write it on kotlin native by texture

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I want to write a flutter video plug-in on Android. I want to write it on kotlin native by texture

Rendering with texture widget on flutter

But I have some problems

He threw out some information

```
call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

I called

```
val texId=IntArray(1);

GLES20.glGenTextures(texId.size,texId,0)
```

he return texId is 0

```
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    print("call ${call.method}")
    when(call.method){
      "getPlatformVersion"->{
        result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
      }
      "playVideo"->{
        val texId=IntArray(1);
        GLES20.glGenTextures(texId.size,texId,0)
        Log.d("autopcDev", "Tex Id : ${texId[0].toString()}")
        val mp=MediaPlay( uri= Uri.fromFile(File((call.arguments as Map<*, *>)["path"] as String)),context = activity)
        result.success(mp.tex[0])
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**glSurfaceView does not run on the OpenGL thread. The glSurfaceView should be on the main android thread.**

The constructor for ***GLES20 methods***, which could be causing the problem. Try instantiating it after the call to "`setRenderer(render);`" or inside the "`onSurfaceCreated`" method.